# Yii2 kartik switchinput in one view with multiple forms not working

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v, multiple-forms

First of all thank you for your attention. I'm trying to handle multiple forms in one view and a have no luck with that.

**view.php**

```
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\SwitchInput;

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Links');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="link-index">
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($links as $link):?>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <?php
                $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => $link->_id,
                    'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL
                ]); ?>
                <?= $form->field($link, 'url') ?>
                <?= $form->field($link, 'active')->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'size' => 'medium',
                        'onColor' => 'success',
                        'offColor' => 'danger',
                    ],
                    'pluginEvents'=>[
                        "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch" => "function(item) { console.log(item); }"
                    ]]); ?>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here it is result:**

[image]

**And console output (no errors)**

[image]

I think that i've chosed correct way to render forms for all my models objects? Huh?

Comment: posted an answer, see if that helps you out

Comment: hey, do get some time out to select the answer as correct as it could help others having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

As per our discussion the OP is not trying to initialize on the same field but instead there are multiple models with the same field name and you are displaying them using `foreach`, so what i would suggest doing is,

1. Inside your `foreach` use the static call to the widget without model
2. introduce a `$counter` field and use it inside your loop to name the input fields.
3. Display the `switchInput` without using ActiveForm  and the original `active` status field should be added as a hidden field inside the `form`.
4. Then use the `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` event to keep the value of the `hidden` field synchronized with the `switchInput` field.

In this way you dont have to worry about loading the value to the model field manually when you submit the form and validate and then save the data to your database table, but you might have to load the field manually when you have to edit, just use the `value` option of the `switchInput` to load the respective model field value.

You might already be using something as a counter in the `foreach` loop if not use one now. see below if that helps you out.I  would be adding a simple `$counter` to show you what i am saying, you can modify that according to your needs.

Here is the sample code so that you get what i am suggesting

```
//the counter 
$counter = 1;

//the foreach loop
foreach(...){
//your form 
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form_' . $counter]);

//call the switchInput without activeform or model
echo SwitchInput::widget([
    'name' => 'fake_status_' . $counter,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'onColor' => 'success',
        'offColor' => 'danger',
    ], 'pluginEvents' => [
        "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch" => "function(item) { 
             if($(item.currentTarget).is(':checked')){ 
                 $('#status_" . $counter . "').val(1)
             }else{ 
                 $('#status_" . $counter . "').val(0)} 
         }"
    ]
]);

//the original status field
$form->field($model, 'status', ['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'status_' . $counter]])->hiddenInput();

ActiveForm::end();
$counter++;
}
```

---

You cannot use multiple switches with the same `input` or `model field` that is why you are having this issue, because `switchInput` initializes the script by assigning the `id`, and you are trying to initialize it on the same field name 3 different time, there cannot be multiple elements with the same `id` so the `javascript/jquery` by nature initializes the plugin on the first element that matches, try initializing without `model` with different `names`.

```
echo SwitchInput::widget([
    'name' => 'status',
    'pluginOptions' => [

        'size' => 'medium' ,
        'onColor' => 'success' ,
        'offColor' => 'danger' ,
    ],'pluginEvents' => [
        "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch" => "function(item) { console.log(item); }"
]
]);


echo SwitchInput::widget([
    'name' => 'status2',
    'pluginOptions' => [

        'size' => 'medium' ,
        'onColor' => 'success' ,
        'offColor' => 'danger' ,
    ],'pluginEvents' => [
        "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch" => "function(item) { console.log(item); }"
]
]);
```

or declare custom fields inside the model with different names say `$status`,`$status2` and then use them to initialize with `model`.

```
echo $form->field ( $model , 'status' )->widget ( SwitchInput::classname () , [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'size' => 'medium' ,
        'onColor' => 'success' ,
        'offColor' => 'danger' ,
    ] ,
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch" => "function(item) { console.log(item); }"
] ] );
echo $form->field ( $model , 'status2' )->widget ( SwitchInput::classname () , [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'size' => 'medium' ,
        'onColor' => 'success' ,
        'offColor' => 'danger' ,
    ] ,
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch" => "function(item) { console.log(item); }"
] ] );
```

Comment: Well, your suggestion is completely right in case with multiple fields in one form. But i initialize new form with unique id for each model object every time (foreach (....) { $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => $link->_id,
                    'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL
                ]);  }

Comment: and in all the `models` you have the same name field for status?

Comment: @StepanStepanov just updated the answer please see if that helps you out

Comment: wow, i thought that activeform and widgets been created to solve problems with multiple fields from models in one view. Or maybe this is a bug in kartik widget? Why don't they use class selectors and initialize inputs in forms scope?

Comment: @StepanStepanov yes I would say they should use a class selector or provide an `option` in the plugin where we can specify which selector we want to use either `id` or `class` and the js plugin should then be initialized with it, but anyhow hope this could get you going with what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem as the author of the topic. Here's the solution:

```
<?= $form->field($link, 'active')->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'size' => 'medium',
        'onColor' => 'success',
        'offColor' => 'danger',
     ],
     'options' => [
         'id' => $link->_id // !!!
     ],
 ]); ?>
```

> SwitchInput widgets must have various id's, because the id is used when rendering the widget.

Comment: A brief tip on why this works would be nice.

Comment: SwitchInput widgets must have various id, because id is used when rendering the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't create multiple instances of this widget with one only model property.

Example:
1) does not work:

```
<?= $form->field($link, 'active')->widget(SwitchInput::classname()
<?= $form->field($link, 'active')->widget(SwitchInput::classname()
```

2) if you want it works, you need different unique properties from model:

```
<?= $form->field($link, 'active0')->widget(SwitchInput::classname()
<?= $form->field($link, 'active1')->widget(SwitchInput::classname()
```

But as to generate for every unique field unique model properties - it's not a deal at all - better solve this moment through the modelless version of kartik widget:

```
echo '<label class="control-label">Status</label>';
echo SwitchInput::widget(['name'=>'status_1', 'value'=>true]);
echo '<label class="control-label">Status</label>';
echo SwitchInput::widget(['name'=>'status_2', 'value'=>true]);
```

Source for answer taken from [kartik switchinput widget page](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/switchinput#basic-usage), hope, it helps if not for author of question, but the next people, who will find this question (as found I, when I was searching solution of this problem)